# No puedo mostrar la data de Firestore

Tags: android-studio, firebase, flutter, app, bloc

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]estoy aprendiendo flutter, BLoC, Firestone con una serie de videos (dejo el link del capitulo), y estaba tratando de traer la coleccion de Firestore y mostrarla en el CarouselSlider como en el video. Pero no me deja mostrarlo en el Carousel porque se me clava en el estado de CategoryLoading y me muestra el CircularProgressIndicator(). Alguna idea de como solucionarlo?

Este seria el capitulo de la serie-> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O8-Q6RyO8QY&list=PLCAZyR6zw2px5C7L2cCG4aywx6g58MIoP&index=25

main.dart

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider(create: (_) => FavoritesBloc()..add(StartFavorites())),
        BlocProvider(
            create: (_) =>
                CheckoutServiceBloc()..add(CheckoutServiceStarted())),
        BlocProvider(
          create: (_) => CategoryBloc(
            categoryRepository: CategoryRepository(),
          )..add(LoadCategories()),
        ),
        BlocProvider(
          create: (_) => ServiceBloc(
            serviceRepository: ServiceRepository(),
          )..add(LoadServices()),
        ),
      ],
```

home.dart

```
BlocBuilder<CategoryBloc, CategoryState>(
            builder: (context, state) {
              if (state is CategoryLoading){
                return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
              }
              if (state is CategoryLoaded){
                return CarouselSlider(
                  options: CarouselOptions(
                    aspectRatio: 1.5,
                    viewportFraction: 0.9,
                    enlargeCenterPage: true,
                    enableInfiniteScroll: true,
                    enlargeStrategy: CenterPageEnlargeStrategy.height,
                  ),
                  items: state.categories
                      .map((category) => HeroCarouselCard(category: category))
                      .toList(),
                );
              }
              else{
                return Text("Something went Wrong");
              }
            },
          ),
```

category_model.dart

```
static Category fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snap) {
    Category category = Category(
      name: snap['name'],
      urlImage: snap['imageUrl'],
    );
    return category;
  }
```

category_base_repo.dart

```
abstract class BaseCategoryRepository {
  Stream<List<Category>> getAllCategories();
}
```

category_repo.dart

```
class CategoryRepository extends BaseCategoryRepository {
  final FirebaseFirestore _firebaseFirestore;

  CategoryRepository({FirebaseFirestore? firebaseFirestore})
      : _firebaseFirestore = firebaseFirestore ?? FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  @override
  Stream<List<Category>> getAllCategories() {
    return _firebaseFirestore
        .collection("categories")
        .snapshots()
        .map((snapshot) {
          return snapshot.docs.map((doc) => Category.fromSnapshot(doc)).toList();
    });
  }
}
```

category_bloc.dart

```
class CategoryBloc extends Bloc<CategoryEvent, CategoryState> {
  final CategoryRepository _categoryRepository;
  StreamSubscription? _categorySubscription;

  CategoryBloc({required CategoryRepository categoryRepository})
      : _categoryRepository = categoryRepository,
        super(CategoryLoading());

  @override
  Stream<CategoryState> mapEventToState(CategoryEvent event) async* {
    if (event is LoadCategories) {
      yield* _mapLoadCategoriesToState();
    }
    if (event is UpdateCategories) {
      yield* _mapUpdateCategoriesToState(event);
    }
  }

  Stream<CategoryState> _mapLoadCategoriesToState() async* {
    _categorySubscription?.cancel();
    _categorySubscription = _categoryRepository
        .getAllCategories()
        .listen((categories) => add(UpdateCategories(categories)));
  }

  Stream<CategoryState> _mapUpdateCategoriesToState(
      UpdateCategories event) async* {
    yield CategoryLoaded(categories: event.categories);
  }
}
```

category_event.dart

```
abstract class CategoryEvent extends Equatable {
  const CategoryEvent();
}

class LoadCategories extends CategoryEvent{

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [];
}

class UpdateCategories extends CategoryEvent{
  final List<Category> categories;

  UpdateCategories(this.categories);

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [categories];
}
```

category_state.dart

```
abstract class CategoryState extends Equatable {
  const CategoryState();
}

class CategoryLoading extends CategoryState {

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class CategoryLoaded extends CategoryState {
  final List<Category> categories;

  CategoryLoaded({this.categories = const <Category> []});

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [categories];
}
```

Comment: Pon un breakpoint en esta parte `_mapUpdateCategoriesToState` para ver si se ejecuta.

Comment: No lo ejecuta, me aparece ```W/DynamiteModule(11257): Local module descriptor class for providerinstaller not found.
I/DynamiteModule(11257): Considering local module providerinstaller:0 and remote module providerinstaller:0```

Comment: Ponlo dentro de `mapEventToState` y dale step over al debuger para que te vayas paso a paso.

Comment: @loki hice eso, me aparecio que llega a CategoryBloc.mapEventToState (category_bloc.dart:22) y de ahi sale. Si le doy un step over me salta a la segunda condicion if que seria el Update, me marca el event en rojo

Comment: Dentro de `mapEventToState ` checa cual es el valor de `event`.